# Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file

Tags: c#, ioexception, filesystemwatcher

I am not sure how to solve this error.

**Update**

[Zen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64781474/11626550) solved this error for when the `LogFile\FWLog.txt` file already exists, but the error still persists when the `LogFile\FWLot.txt` doesn't exist.

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\CodeWorkspace\NET\fw\fw\LogFile\FWLog.txt' because it is being used by another process.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path, Boolean checkHost)
> at FW.CreateLog(String logName, String path, DateTime time)
> at FW.Watch(String path)
> at FW.Run()
> at FW.Main()

Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class FW
{
    private static StreamWriter log;
    public static void Main()
    {
        Run();
    }

    private static void Run()
    {
        string option = "";
        Console.WriteLine("File System Watcher\nThis program monitors activity in a specified directory.");
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (args.Length >= 2)
        {
            String path = args[1];
            Watch(path);
        }
        while (!option.Equals("3"))
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Choose an option:\n[1] Monitor a direcotry.\n[2] Open log history\n[3] Quit\n>> ");
                option = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (!option.Equals("1") && !option.Equals("2") && !option.Equals("3"));
            switch (option)
            {
                case "1":
                    Watch("");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    if ((Directory.Exists("LogFile") && !File.Exists("LogFile\\FWLog.txt")) || !Directory.Exists("LogFile"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There are no saved logs.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nLog History");
                        DumpLog("LogFile\\FWLog.txt");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Quiting...");
    }

    //[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    private static void Watch(string path)
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        string logName = "LogFile\\FWLog.txt";
        while (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter a valid absolute directory path (i.e. C:\\Users\\john\\Documents)\n>> ");
            path = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Monitoring: " + path);
        CreateLog(logName, path, time);
        log = File.AppendText(logName);
        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
        {
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            watcher.Path = path;

            // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
            // the renaming of files or directories.
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                 | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                 | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            watcher.Created += OnChanged;
            watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
            watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // Wait for the user to quit the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to stop monitoring.");
            while (!(Console.ReadLine()).Equals("q")) ;
        }
        log.Close();
    }
    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string status = $"{Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath)} in {Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath)} {e.ChangeType} {DateTime.Now}";
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        if ((e.FullPath).Contains("LogFile\\FWLog.txt"))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(status);
            log.WriteLine(status);
        }
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        string status = $"{Path.GetFileName(e.OldFullPath)} Renamed to {Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath)} in {Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath)} {DateTime.Now}";
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine(status);
        log.WriteLine(status);
    }

    private static void CreateLog(string logName, string path, DateTime time)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists("LogFile"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory("LogFile");
        if (!File.Exists(logName))
            File.Create(logName);
        using (StreamWriter logCreate = File.AppendText(logName))
        {
            if (File.ReadAllBytes(logName).Length == 0)
            {
                logCreate.WriteLine($"Monitored: {path} {time}");
            }
            else
            {
                logCreate.WriteLine($"\nMonitored: {path} {time}");
            }
            logCreate.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void DumpLog(string logFile)
    {
        string line;
        if (File.ReadAllBytes(logFile).Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Log file is empty.");
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamReader r = File.OpenText(logFile))
            {
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"the error still persists when the LogFile\FWLot.txt doesn't exist."_ -- no, it doesn't. The file exists as soon as you create it, and the error happens after that point in time. See duplicates for alternative means to deal with the file that won't cause the exception.

Comment: Do you still have the `File.Create(logName)` in the method `CreateLog`? Remove it. `File.Create` returns a `FileStream`object and you don't know when the GC will free this object. `File.AppendText` will by itself create a new file, if it does not exists. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @GWimpassinger Thank you. That worked. I didn't read the documentation for ```File.AppendText``` very thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method `CreateLog`, you're trying to read a file with `File.ReadAllBytes`. However, this file has been open by [File.AppendText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=net-5.0) before read operation, that's why exception occurs. You can check if file empty before writing operation to avoid this exception.

Please refer to code below for part of method `CreateLog`.

```cs
            bool isFileEmpty = File.ReadAllBytes(logName).Length == 0;
            using (StreamWriter logCreate = File.AppendText(logName))
            {
                if (isFileEmpty)
                {
                    logCreate.WriteLine($"Monitored: {path} {time}");
                }
                else
                {
                    logCreate.WriteLine($"\nMonitored: {path} {time}");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Actually, something interesting occurred. This works when the 'LogFile' folder and 'FWLog.txt' already exist, but when the file does not exist, the same IOException occurs.